# Bootstrap select redirect to option value link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to redirect to a page based on the selected option value from the bootstrap select.

HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">Home</option>
    <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Ask Question</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

This is my code but it's not working:

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectpicker', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: What errors do you get in your browser's console?

Comment: @j08691 there are no errors on the console when I select an option the browser refresh the page only not redirect to the link that inside the option value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the selected option

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectpicker', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
});
```